# What are some Domain Specific Languages (DSLs) for GIS?

Tags: map-algebra

I'm curious what sort of [domain specific languages](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/DomainSpecificLanguage.html) (DSLs) are used in GIS.  The only one I can think of is the DOCELL language that was provided in ArcInfo Workstation GRID, but is no longer supported.

Comment: Please add the definition rather than linking to an external website which may change content/go offline anytime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [FME](http://www.safe.com/)'s workbench would classify as a graphical DSL, and its generated/editable scripts as a DSL
- ArcGIS's Model Builder could also be described as a graphical DSL.
- MapServer's [MapFile](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/index.html) syntax (and the language agnostic [MapScript](http://mapserver.org/mapscript/introduction.html))
- [SLD](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sld) is described as an encoding, but may also fall under the category of an DSL.

Answer (score 6):

Map algebra likely qualifies. The data model provided with GDAL (similar to DOCELL), and its [VRT format](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html).  The [simple features](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfs) model implemented in software such as PostGIS, as an object-relational database extension for domain-specific data.

Answer (score 2):

MapBasic, the macro langage of Mapinfo ?

Answer (score 1):

If a DSL can include SQL, I imagine that Avenue would be included.

Comment: Isn't Avenue a dead language? Does ESRI sell ArcView 3.x anymore?

Comment: If by dead you mean that it is not actively developed anymore or that hardly anyone uses it, then it is dead.  But if it is a domain-specific language it is a valid answer for the question.  Since we haven't seen a definition of DSL we can't know that at this point.